# Are these two events $A$ and $B$ independent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Abe and Bernard are dealt five cards each from the same $52$ card deck. Let $A$ be the event that Abe gets a flush (five cards of the same suit) and $B$ be the event that Bernard’s five cards are of pairwise different kinds (i.e. pairwise independent). Are $A$ and $B$ independent?

**Thoughts.** Is $P(A) = P(A|B)$? In other words, is the probability of $A$ the same as the probability of $A$ given that $B$ occurred?

Comment: I think this may depend heavily on whether Abe and Bernard were dealt their five cards on the same hand or on different hands.

Comment: Define "Pairwise different kinds."  Do you mean that there are no two cards in his hand that are the same rank (*i.e. number such as 2,3,A,J,K,...*)?  I.e. there is no pair, three of a kind, or four of a kind in his hand?

Comment: @Joanpemo: There is only one reasonable interpretation of this question: they were dealt their five cards on the same hand.

Answer (score 1):

(*this answer assumes "flush" is meant to also include the possibility of straight flush or royal flushes*)

From earlier example, we know $Pr(A)=\frac{4\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$ and we know $Pr(B)=\frac{4^5\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}$

Let us attempt to calculate $Pr(A\cap B)$.  Our sample space will be all ways in which Abe and Bernard can be dealt five card hands.  There are $\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}$ possibilities.

Suppose Abe is dealt a flush.  This can occur in $4\binom{13}{5}$ number of ways.  Given this as already occurring, the number of ways of Bernard avoiding any pairs will depend on the number of cards of the same rank as Abe's, so continue via cases.

- No cards match: $\binom{8}{5}\cdot 4^5$
- One card matches:  $5\cdot 3\cdot \binom{8}{4}4^4$
- Two cards match:  $\binom{5}{2}\cdot 3^2\cdot \binom{8}{3}4^3$
- Three cards match:  $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3^3\cdot \binom{8}{2}4^2$
- Four cards match:  $\binom{5}{4}\cdot 3^4\cdot \binom{8}{1}4$
- Five cards match: $\binom{5}{5}\cdot 3^5$

[There are](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288+choose+5%294%5E5%2B5*3*%288+choose+4%294%5E4%2B%285+choose+2%293%5E2*%288+choose+3%294%5E3%2B%285+choose+3%293%5E3*%288+choose+2%294%5E2%2B5*3%5E4*8*4%2B3%5E5) $782867$ number of ways in which given a particular flush hand of Abe's that Bernard receives five distinct ranks.

The number of ways in which $A$ and $B$ can then happen simultaneously is $782867\cdot 4\cdot \binom{13}{5}$

The probability $Pr(A\cap B)$ is then $\frac{4\binom{13}{5}\cdot 782867}{\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}} = \frac{46051}{45553340}\approx 0.0010109$

We have $Pr(A)Pr(B) = \frac{4\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}\frac{4^5\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}} = \frac{17424}{17347225}\approx 0.0010044$

As these are unequal, they are dependent events.

---

This answer can be reworded as though we calculated $Pr(B|A)$ and checked to see if it was equal to $Pr(B)$.  This was an easier route to take than checking if $Pr(A|B)=Pr(A)$ as there would be even more cases to consider based on the arrangement of suits in Bernard's hand.